# Firefox opens popup video with AdBlocker and Block Popups on

Tags: firefox, video, popups

I use Firefox with Ad Blocker and some sites still popup a video box in one of the lower corners of the page.  The video player is from Connatix and I don't see any settings menu that would allow me to turn off auto play.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: Try third-party tools such as PopUpOFF, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/popupoff/

Comment: I'm already using Add Blocker

Comment: There's lots of Ad Blockers. By not being specific you're not giving us enough information.

Comment: Firefox is the specific browser I am using.  "Ad Blocker" is a specific ad blocker product and Connatix is a specific video player that isn't being blocked. What more specifics would you suggest I add to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adblocker didn't close annoying popups. That's where I created PopUpOFF:

https://youtu.be/3jTKRCxLyPE

Comment: I tired PopUpOff and the good news is its easy to install, works and sites aren't looking for it like Ad Blocker.  Bad news is the Connatix viewer still plays.  Like @bean delivery man said, I don't think there's much that can be done about that.

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Aggressive" mode? If it's still plays, send me a link, I'll try to fix it with the next update :)

Comment: Aggressive mode doesn't help.  I'm thinking its just part of the web site and may not be a pop up.  Here's the link, you have to wait a minuet or two for the video to play:   https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/

Comment: I found a solution, AdNauseam.  Works better than Ad Blocker and blocks this specific player.   I'd add this as an answer but the question was incorrectly closed.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there's not much to be done. If you're spending an excessive amount of time on that site, try using inspect element to hide it.

Comment: Not sure how I would hide an element from someone else's page.  I don't spend excessive time on the site, as a matter of fact it happens on multiple sites but always the same player, Connatix.